# How to include a file that stay in STATIC directory into a Django template inheritance

Tags: python, django, templates

I have the following directory in django app.

```
.
|-- migrations
|-- static
|   |-- help_content.html
|   |-- images
|   `-- vendors
`-- templates
    `-- coolapp
        |-- other_content.html
        `-- parent.html
```

Now in `parent.html` I'd like to able to do this:

```
{% include "../static/help_content.html" %}
```

But it fails. What's the right way to do it?

This is ok though:

```
{% include "coolap/other_content.html" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The include tag, will look for your specified file on "TEMPLATES_DIR" setting. For sure, the static folder is not included, and shouldn't (is possible but not too coherent)

I think you should move "help_content.html" inside of "templates" folder, you can put it in another folder inside "templates" if you want to keep some order there.

The Static folder is meant to store .css, .js and that kind of files, which you can include using "static" template tag for example.

Hope this help you.